# Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Although there is other posts about this but for some reason I still keep getting the error.[javascript error message cannot be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMHKz.png)

Comment: Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Home#index

Comment: from tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyvWz5TUWg